# SharePoint Source control plugin for VS?

Tags: visual-studio, source-control

Yes, it might sound like a strange thing to ask for.

We're a team of 3-4 person working on a sln that is only developed using the Client Object Model. So we rather have no deployment, just a bunch of js files.

But we've not found a good way of working together. (We're using a dummy vs project, and linking in the files - that is everyone working on the serverfiles) What I like do have is a VS plugin that allows me to work against our sharepoint libraries just as we would if the files where in TFS.

Anyone got other ways of doing this?

Regards

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity, why don't you deploy your solution as a WSP file (a Module) into the sandbox?

Comment: We're sitting on old 32 bit XP's - no SP tools...

Comment: ...but thanks for the suggestion :-)

Comment: Ok, there is no VS-SP plugin. So you have to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configure SharePoint to accept dll, exe that you will be generating during debug or prod release.